# how to switch to frame that uses yui

Tags: selenium, iframe, webdriver

Hi I'm currently trying to switch iframes but I do not know how to switch it to this frame, as its id uses yui which is forever dynamic, currently using selenium with eclipse luna using google chrome as my webdriver browser

```
<iframe class="dialog-iframe-node " frameborder="0" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1436845377989_182_iframe_" name="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1436845377989_182_iframe_" src="https://mo-sit.nets.com.sg/group/main/pr-enquiry?p_p_id=p2p_Procurement_Enquiry_WAR_morp2pportlet&amp;p_p_lifecycle=0&amp;p_p_state=pop_up&amp;p_p_mode=view&amp;p_p_col_id=column-1&amp;p_p_col_count=1&amp;_p2p_Procurement_Enquiry_WAR_morp2pportlet_action=renderGRNApplicationsPopup&amp;_p2p_Procurement_Enquiry_WAR_morp2pportlet_appNo=PR020150102506&amp;yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1436845377989_183=1436845380806" style="height: 351px; width: 1024px;"></iframe>
```

whole html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1437015884634_696" class="aui ltr yui3-js-enabled gecko ltr js firefox firefox37 firefox37-0 win secure" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
<div id="yui3-css-stamp" class="" style="position: absolute !important; visibility: hidden !important"></div>
<head>
<body id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1437015884634_695" class="red yui3-skin-sam controls-visible guest-site signed-in private-page site">
<div class="yui3-widget-mask" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 1202;"></div>
<div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1437015884634_782" class="yui3-widget modal yui3-widget-positioned yui3-widget-modal yui3-widget-stacked modal-focused yui3-dd-draggable yui3-resize" style="height: 400px; width: 1024px; left: 397.5px; top: 5.89999px; z-index: 1202;" tabindex="0">
<div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1437015884634_795" class="modal-content yui3-widget-stdmod yui3-widget-content-expanded">
<div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1437015884634_1144" class="yui3-widget-hd modal-header">
<div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1437015884634_1005" class="yui3-widget-bd modal-body dialog-iframe-bd" style="max-height: 400px; height: 351px; padding: 0px;">
<iframe id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1437015884634_782_iframe_" class="dialog-iframe-node " frameborder="0" src="https://mo-uat.nets.com.sg/group/main/pr-enquiry?p_p_id=p2p_Procurement_Enquiry_WAR_morp2pportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=pop_up&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_p2p_Procurement_Enquiry_WAR_morp2pportlet_action=renderGRNApplicationsPopup&_p2p_Procurement_Enquiry_WAR_morp2pportlet_appNo=PR020150706783&yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1437015884634_783=1437016436400" name="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1437015884634_782_iframe_" style="height: 351px; width: 1024px;">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="aui ltr yui3-js-enabled gecko ltr js firefox firefox37 firefox37-0 win secure dialog-iframe-root-node" lang="en-US" dir="ltr" style="padding: 15px;">
</iframe>
<div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1437015884634_951" class="loadingmask yui3-widget component overlay overlaymask yui3-widget-positioned yui3-widget-stacked overlaymask-hidden" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 351px; width: 1024px; z-index: 1000;">
</div>
</div>
<div class="yui3-resize-handles-wrapper">
</div>
<div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1437015884634_515" class="yui3-dd-shim" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; z-index: 9999; overflow: hidden; background-color: red; display: none; height: 5px; width: 5px;"></div>
<div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1437015884634_222" class="yui3-widget modal yui3-widget-positioned yui3-widget-modal yui3-widget-stacked yui3-dd-draggable yui3-resize modal-hidden" style="height: 400px; width: 1024px; left: 2921px; top: 1107px; z-index: 1201;" tabindex="0">
<div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1437015884634_237" class="modal-content yui3-widget-stdmod yui3-widget-content-expanded">
<div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1437015884634_474" class="yui3-widget-hd modal-header">
<div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1437015884634_611" class="yui3-widget-bd modal-body dialog-iframe-bd" style="max-height: 400px; height: 351px; padding: 0px;">
<iframe id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1437015884634_222_iframe_" class="dialog-iframe-node " frameborder="0" src="https://mo-uat.nets.com.sg/group/main/pr-enquiry?p_p_id=p2p_Procurement_Enquiry_WAR_morp2pportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=pop_up&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_p2p_Procurement_Enquiry_WAR_morp2pportlet_action=renderGRNApplicationsPopup&_p2p_Procurement_Enquiry_WAR_morp2pportlet_appNo=PR020150706784&yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1437015884634_223=1437015894284" name="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1437015884634_222_iframe_" style="height: 351px; width: 1024px;">
<div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1437015884634_420" class="loadingmask yui3-widget component overlay overlaymask yui3-widget-positioned yui3-widget-stacked overlaymask-hidden" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 0px; width: 0px; z-index: 1000;">
</div>
</div>
<div class="yui3-resize-handles-wrapper">
</div>
<a id="skip-to-content" href="#main-content">Skip to Content</a>
<div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1437015884634_729" class="wrapper">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one frame on page you can use the following code (on Python)

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe"))
```

In general case you should find some unique characteristic of this frame, for example, it can be child of another element with unique id etc

Comment: the parent id is also dynamic. :(

Comment: Could you post whole html?